# XEN disk mapping problem under opensolaris

Tags: debian, opensolaris, xen

I have a system with two harddisks, i wanted to use the simplicity of ZFS for my file server and i also need to run a linux. I choosed XEN virtualization for that, supported on both system.

My GRUB is well configured and i can boot both system.

I would like is to run both system with solaris as a `dom0` and the debian installed on the 2nd HD as a virtual machine.

My problem is that i want to use the partitions of my 1st harddisk (sda1 under linux) and it does not work. I didn't find my use case on the web-

Here is my Opensolaris device name of this partition : `/dev/rdsk/c7d0p1` But when i use : `disk = [ 'phy:rdsk/c7d0p1,sda1,w' ]` as a disk mapping in my XEN configuration file i have the error :

```
Error: Device 2049 (vbd) could not be connected. error: "rdsk/c7d0p1" is not a valid block device.
```

I am "lost".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was the /dev/rdsk the r of rdsk mean read only to be able to read and write you need to use /dev/dsk/
I put my setting because it is really interesting.
On my Opensolaris machine i did un full upgrade and install XEN.

Here is my full config file :

```
name="debian"
memory='2047'
cpus='1'
vcpus='1'
bootloader = '/usr/lib/xen/bin/pygrub'
ramdisk ="/boot/initrd.img-2.6.26-2-xen-amd64"
kernel ="/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.26-2-xen-amd64"
on_shutdown = 'destroy'
on_reboot = 'restart'
on_crash = 'restart'
vif = [ '' ]
disk = [ 'phy:/dev/dsk/c7d0p0,sda,w' ]
extra="kerne /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.26-1-xen-amd64 root=/dev/sda1 ro console=tty0"
```

I map the HD directly to sda. I don't have to mange the partition here no swap problem etc etc ...

Comment: Your first sentence is unintelligible. Also, "to manage" vs "to mange" in the last one would be clearer.